# Checking for several different exe's running with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, process, tasklist

So currently I'm using:

```
 :METFEXTLOOP1
 tasklist | find /i "Full_Index_Update.exe" >nul 2>&1
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 GOTO METFEXTLOOP2
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO The Full Index Update is Running...
 ping localhost -n 3 >nul
 cls
 GOTO METFEXTLOOP1
 )
 ::Verify Early Index Update Is not Running
 :METFEXTLOOP2
 tasklist | find /i "Early_Index_Update.exe" >nul 2>&1
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 GOTO METFEXTLOOP3
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO The Early Index Update is Running...
 ping localhost -n 3 >nul
 cls
 GOTO METFEXTLOOP2
)
 ::Verify Morningstar US Mutual Funds Extended is not Running
:METFEXTLOOP3
 tasklist | find /i "MstarExt.exe" >nul 2>&1
 IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
 GOTO METFEXTLOOP4
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO The Morningstar US Mutual Funds Extended Update is Running...
 ping localhost -n 3 >nul
 cls
 GOTO METFEXTLOOP3
 )
 :METFEXTLOOP4
 ECHO Hello World
 pause
```

And that works fine, but what I'd like to do is consolidate it more, since this check is performed after each additional update is being run. I thought I was being clever with:

```
    @ECHO OFF
    :FullLOOP
        tasklist | find /i "SA_8.5_Setup.exe" >nul 2>&1
        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
            tasklist | find /i "Early Index.exe" >nul 2>&1
            IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                tasklist | find /i "MorningstarUSMutualFundsBasic.exe" >nul 2>&1
                IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                    tasklist | find /i "MorningstarUSMoneyMarketFundsBasic.exe" >nul 2>&1
                    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                        tasklist | find /i "MorningstarETFBasic.exe" >nul 2>&1
                        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                            tasklist | find /i "MorningstarUSMutualFundsExtended.exe" >nul 2>&1
                            IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                                tasklist | find /i "LipperUSMutualFundsExtended.exee" >nul 2>&1
                                IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                                    tasklist | find /i "LipperUSMutualFundsBasic.exe" >nul 2>&1
                                    IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                                        tasklist | find /i "LipperUSMutualFundsBasic.exe" >nul 2>&1
                                        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                                            tasklist | find /i "PSNExtended.exe" >nul 2>&1
                                            IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                                                tasklist | find /i "PSNBasic.exe" >nul 2>&1
                                                GOTO Proceed
            ) ELSE (
                    ECHO Another installer is running....
                    ping localhost -n 3 >nul
                    cls
                    GOTO FullLOOP
                    )
    :Proceed
    cls
    ECHO Hello World
    pause
```

However this crashes almost immediately. Is there a "cheating" way of doing this? Or do I need to do multiple loops in order to make these checks. This is probably a dumb and obvious mistake on my part. However any assistance with this would be very welcome and appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps.

```html
@echo off
:FullLOOP
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq SA_8.5_Setup.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "SA_8.5_Setup.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq Early Index.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Early Index.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MorningstarUSMutualFundsBasic.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "Early MorningstarUSMutualFundsBasic.exe">NUL 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MorningstarUSMutualFundsBasic.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "MorningstarUSMutualFundsBasic.exe">NUL 
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MorningstarUSMoneyMarketFundsBasic.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "MorningstarUSMoneyMarketFundsBasic.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MorningstarETFBasic.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "MorningstarETFBasic.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq MorningstarUSMutualFundsExtended.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "MorningstarUSMutualFundsExtended.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq LipperUSMutualFundsExtended.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "LipperUSMutualFundsExtended.exee">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq LipperUSMutualFundsBasic.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "LipperUSMutualFundsBasic.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq PSNExtended.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "PSNExtended.exe">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" ( 
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq PSNBasic.exe" 2>NUL | find /I /N "PSNBasic.exe">NUL
GOTO Proceed
)))))))))) else (
                    ECHO Another installer is running....
                    ping localhost -n 3 >nul
      cls
                    GOTO FullLOOP
                    )
pause
    :Proceed
    cls
    ECHO Hello World
    pause
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, however this doesn't seem to work. It doesn't re-check continuously, or doesn't seem to. It'll Either get stuck on "Another installer is running...." or "Hello World"  (proceeding with installing additional items). I've gotta say though, it's a much prettier loop than my long chain of them though. I've been tinkering with it and can't seem to get it to work. Is there a way to check tasklist for if %this% or %that% or %other% =1 then proceed else check again.